# VB.NET get between all strings one by one

Tags: vb.net, string

so this code checks only once between

```
  Private Function GetBetween(ByVal sSearch As String, ByVal sStart As String, _
           ByVal sStop As String, Optional ByVal lSearch As Integer = 1) As String
    Dim lTemp As Long

    lSearch = InStr(lSearch, sSearch, sStart)
    If lSearch > 0 Then
        lSearch += Len(sStart)
        lTemp = InStr(lSearch, sSearch, sStop)
        If lTemp > lSearch Then
            GetBetween = Trim(Mid(sSearch, lSearch, lTemp - lSearch))
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

i got this string the string is not stable i mean there can be more players then this http://pastebin.com/JTi51nBV and i want to show the text between player  /player one by one for example in messagebox.
sorry for my english

Comment: That text is XML. Use `System.Xml` to parse XML contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the correct tool to parse XML, `System.Xml.XmlDocument`:

```
' Add the namespace at the top
Imports System.Xml
' And then ...
Dim sXml As String = "YOUR_XML_STRING_HERE"
Dim doc As New XmlDocument
doc.PreserveWhitespace = True
doc.LoadXml(sXml)
For Each Entry As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("//player")
    Console.WriteLine(Entry.InnerXml)
Next
```

See the [VB.NET demo here](https://ideone.com/AQmvYS).

If you do not need the tags to be shown, replace `Entry.InnerXml` with `Entry.InnerText`.

Note that the `//player` is an XPath expression that gets all `<player>` nodes.

Comment: i need the tags to be shown thats ok anyway again thank you so much

Comment: Good, it is up to you.